# iOS Smart App Banner Not Recognizing Device/Compatibility

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I'm having problems with the behaviour of iOS Smart App Banners.  I have an iOS app that is compatible with iOS 7 or later, and have added the smart app banner meta tag to my wbesite.  In spite of this, I see the smart app banner on a device running iOS 6 and I don't see the smart app banner on a device running iOS 8, which is the opposite of what should happen.

My understanding from the [Smart App Banner Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) is that:

> Smart App Banners automatically determine whether the app is supported on the user’s device. If the device loading the banner does not support your app, or if your app is not available in the user's location, the banner will not display.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing History and Website Data in Safari resulted in the Smart App Banner appearing in iOS8.  Re-reading the [Smart App Banner Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html), I realized that the Smart App Banner doesn't discriminate if the app is not supported by your version of iOS, only if the app is not supported by your *device*.  As such, a Smart App Banner for an app that requires iOS7 will appear on a device running iOS6, even if that device doesn't support iOS7.